# How do I truncate a list in C#?

Tags: c#, list, truncate

I know in python you can do something like `myList[1:20]` but is there anything similar in C#?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
var itemsOneThroughTwenty = myList.Take(20);
var itemsFiveThroughTwenty = myList.Skip(5).Take(15);
```

Comment: Note that these Linq extensions actually create an IEnumerable<> that stops after N items, rather than creating a new array/list.  (This is kind of hidden by using 'var' for the variable type.  If the code following the truncation iterates through the new list lots of times, you'll actually be re-evaluating the expression tree *each time*.  In this case, you might want to tack a `.ToList()` onto the end to force the items to be enumerated and a new list created.

Comment: This does not truncate the list as requested

Answer (score 29):

You can use [`List<T>.GetRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx):

```
var subList = myList.GetRange(0, 20);
```

From MSDN:

> Creates a shallow copy of a range of elements in the source `List<T>`.
>
> `public List<T> GetRange(int index, int count)`

Comment: This does not truncate the list as requested

Answer (score 22):

This might be helpful for efficiency, if you really want to truncate the list, not make a copy.  While the python example makes a copy, the original question really was about truncating the list.

Given a List<> object "list" and you want the 1st through 20th elements

```
list.RemoveRange( 20, list.Count-20 );
```

This does it in place. This is still O(n) as the references to each object must be removed, but should be a little faster than any other method.

Comment: Unless the `list` contains value types, in which case removal of references is skipped in .Net Core.

Comment: @NetMage Good point. You are referring to the O(n) and rightly point out this can be O(1) in those cases

Answer (score 4):

sans LINQ quicky...

```
    while (myList.Count>countIWant) 
       myList.RemoveAt(myList.Count-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> MaxOf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int maxItems)
    {
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();            
        for (int count = 0; count <= maxItems && enumerator.MoveNext(); count++)
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it stands you might consider adding some explanatory text, because less experienced users might struggle to understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The list can be truncated using the `RemoveRange` keyword . The function is as follows:

```
  void List<type>.RemoveRange(int index, int count);
```

This removes the elements from `index` until `count`.
Using this for type int, to remove from 0 to the not required points:

Code:

```
int maxlimit = 100;
List<int> list_1 = new List<int>();
if (list_1.Count > maxLimit){
    list_1.RemoveRange(0, (list_1.Count - maxlimit));
}
```

Comment: not sure what this adds to other answers and the example uses an empty list.