# How to truncate a list?

Tags: c#

What's the easiest way to remove every element after and including the nth element in a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`?

Comment: btw this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428242/how-do-i-truncate-a-list-in-c

Comment: @PandaWood: Yep. But too late now :) Two different solutions too.

Comment: Question header not so adequate to a question. Truncate in SQL means delete all. So the answer would be `list.Clear();` :)

Comment: @PawelCioch This isn't SQL. And that's exactly why you're supposed to read the question body. Truncate [means](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/truncate) "to shorten".

Comment: I'm not native English speaker so some words sticks to one technology or one meaning. Never checked Truncate in the dictionary, so the header was a trigger for SQL :) Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you can use `RemoveRange` method, simply do:

```
list.RemoveRange(index, count);
```

Where index is where to start from and count is how much to remove. So to remove everything from a certain index to the end, the code will be:

```
list.RemoveRange(index, list.Count - index);
```

Conversely, you can use:

```
list.GetRange(index, count);
```

But that will create a new list, which may not be what you want.

Comment: you mean `list.RemoveRange(index, list.Count - index)`?

Comment: Heh, I edited my answer before I saw your comment, but yes, that's what you would do.

Comment: `RemoveRange` is not a LINQ method, it is an instance method of `List<>`.

Comment: In my mind it's more length that index. `list.RemoveRange(len, list.Count - len); // save first len elems in list`

Comment: @CoR - thanks, your comment might have saved 10 minutes of my life!

Comment: This is what I was looking for - if you're only removing elements from the end then no data is copied, only internal 'size' field of the list is updated.

Answer (score 11):

sans LINQ quicky...

```
    while (myList.Count>countIWant) 
       myList.RemoveAt(myList.Count-1);
```

Comment: RemoveRange is probably more efficient and less verbose.

Comment: @ZarShardan How is it less verbose? You have to check if the index exists and calculate the count. If it would allow giving an index that doesn't exist and a count over what actually exists without throwing an exception it would be easier, but as it is, it is actually more verbose.

Comment: @selalerer even with the index check it is only marginally more verbose, but still more efficient.Besides, it communicates the intent better, so easier to read.
if(idx < list.Count) list.RemoveRange(idx, list.Count - idx);

Comment: this works also on ObservableCollection, while RemoveRange doesn't.

Comment: This worked very well to truncate a list to match the length of another list.  It prevents issues with `RemoveRange` at an index of `.Count - 1` when the length of the leading list is `0` (and thus avoids a condition on the value of `.Count`).

Answer (score 3):

```
list.Take(n);
```

Comment: This method will create a new list instead of editing the existing one, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @Daniel T.: that is why i upvoted your answer just after few seconds you've posted it - because yours is more correct and i did not know that extension method ;-)

Comment: @Daniet T, this does not create a new list. It simply allows you to enumerate a sequence of the umutated original list.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: but if the OP needs a `List` as result - he will apply `ToList()` anyway.

Comment: @zerkms, if ToList() were part of your answer, the comment would be correct. But it isn't... so it isn't.

Comment: -1 What does this method do? Does it return a new list? Does it modify the list? How performatic is it? Is there another way to do it? Which is faster?

Comment: This is great for truncating a list returned from a function

Answer (score 2):

If LINQ is not an option, you can loop through the list backwards:

```
for(int i = list.Count - 1; i >= index; i--)
{
    list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: +1 for simple way, though `RemoveRange` is likely to be more efficient.

Comment: RemoveRange is always available when there's List<T>, as it has nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: Ah, neat. I haven't noticed it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample app to do it

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> lint = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        Console.WriteLine("List Elements");
        lint.ForEach(delegate(int i) {  Console.WriteLine(i); });

        lint.RemoveRange(8, lint.Count - 8);

        Console.WriteLine("List Elements after removal");
        lint.ForEach(delegate(int i) { Console.WriteLine(i); });

        Console.Read();

    }
```